# Multiple page counters in a single document with xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Using XSL-FO I want to create a PDF with two different page-numbers on each page. One number will have an offset based on the sum of all pages of previously generated documents, whereas the other number will represent the page number of the current document, without any offset.

For example:
Document 1 has 3 pages numbered as follows, display on different pages separated by comma:

- Header (total numbers): 1, 2, 3
- Footer (local numbers): 1/3, 2/3, 3/3

Document 2 has 4 pages numbered as follows, display on different pages separated by comma:

- Header (total numbers): 4, 5, 6, 7
- Footer (local numbers): 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4

I know that I can set the initial page number in order to show the total pages in the footer, but than I cannot access the local numbers anymore.

I first tried to modify the value of `<fo:page-number />`, for example by setting a variable with the page-number, but as [How to manipulate page number in FOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958515/how-to-manipulate-page-number-in-fop) pointed out, this is not working.

In [How to manipulate page number in FOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958515/how-to-manipulate-page-number-in-fop) also is pointed out that the problem might be solved with reprocessing the [intermediate format](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/intermediate.html), but this seems kind of complex to solve this seemingly simple problem. Is there any way to achieve the desired result in a single processing-step?

To generate the PDF I use Apache FOP.

Thanks, Felix

Comment: Not sure it's possible. You can force restart numbering on the page-sequence, but you can not have at the same time the number of pages considering the whole document and considering a subset of pages.

Comment: The only solution is what you have mentioned -- using the intermediate format. There is only one page number in XSL FO and you cannot do math with the page number or any reference to the page number in pure XSL FO.

Comment: If you were using AH Formatter, you would have the option to use `axf:physical-page-number` and/or `axf:origin-id` to solve your problem.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#page-number